# Asynchronous image uploading in tableview like instant messaging

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, chat, image-uploading, instant-message

I am doing the messaging with the option sending photo, Once the image is picking it will be upload to the server and also display on the chatTableview list. However I want the cell of chatTableview display the progress of photo uploading as well. Could anyone share me the idea how can I update the cell of chatTableview according the status of photo uploading, like in wechat ?[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byk4f4_C6hLMMGVGLXVjQkRDa2s/view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi，you may be able to use multithreading~
For example,

```
NSBlockOperation *operation1 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"sending photo and update the progress of photo - %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
......
}];
NSBlockOperation *operation2 = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"doing the messaging   - %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
......
}];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperations:@[operation1, operation2] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```